# How can I add new field in tier price?

Tags: magento

`app/design/adminhtml/default/default/catalog/product/edit/price/tier.phtml`

Data from one new field `Peice_Price` is successfully showing in the tier page.
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wn6D4.png]
How do I insert the data into table `catalog_product_entity_tier_price`? I want to save this data when product page save button clicked.

Comment: i am not able to understand your question .. can you pls explain with screenshot if possible.

Comment: I know this doesn't help answer your question, but "piece" is spelt with an "ie", not "ei".

Answer (score 0):

**For add tier price, don't touch `tier.phtml` file.**

---

### For add a tier price to product:

**1*/** Set an array with this 4 required keys : `website`, `customer_group_id`, `qty`, `price`.

```
$tierPrice = array(
    'website' => 'all', // or website ID
    'customer_group_id' => 2, // or 'all'
    'qty'  => 20, // required & not null, 1 = for not manage qty
    'price'  => 19.99,
);
```

**2*/** Use `update` method from `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Tierprice_Api` to update product price.

*The method want an array with 1,n tier price:*

```
$tierPrices[] = $tierPrice;
// in example the product ID is 123

try
{
    $api = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Tierprice_Api();
    $api->update( 123 , $tierPrices );
}
catch (Exception $ex)
{
    echo "Error when tier price creation: {$e->getMessage()} \n";
}
```

Show your admin panel, the tier price is stored with the product.

---

### To change tier price for an already existent product.

**1*/** Get the product price array:

```
$api = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Tierprice_Api();
$tiersPrices = $api->info( 123 );  // 123 is the product ID
```

*If you `var_dump($tiersPrices);` you get something like this :*

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["customer_group_id"]=>
    int(1) "2"
    ["website"]=>
    string(3) "all"
    ["qty"]=>
    string(7) "20.0000"
    ["price"]=>
    string(7) "19.9900"
  }
}
```

**2.1*/** To change an existent tier price:

```
$tiersPrices[0]['customer_group_id'] = 'all';
```

**2.2*/** To add one other, set an array:

```
$tiersPrices[] = array(
    'website' => 'all',
    'customer_group_id' => 'all',
    'qty'  => 50,
    'price'  => 14.99,
);
```

**3*/** And update :

```
$api->update( 123 , $tiersPrices );
```

Tier price is updated!

---

The core code is readable and well built enough to find and understand the process.

This is a quick translation for a [french article](http://www.blogoergosum.com/16892-comment-manipuler-les-prix-tiers-dun-produit-magento) writing the 22 jan 2010 by [dbrugne](http://www.blogoergosum.com/author/dbrugne).

Comment: Hello Nolwennig,

Thanks for reply,
I have tried above example its works but When i trying to add new field as i mentioned in screen shot then it will not saved.
$tiersPrices[] = array(
    'website' => 'all',
    'customer_group_id' => 'all',
    'qty'  => 50,
    'piece_price' => 10.00
    'price'  => 14.99,
);